# how to convert a number to float with 8 point decimal places in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, chai

How can i convert a number, a input from my test case which will be of either integer or float, into a float/string number of always with 8 decimal places? say for example, if my input is 3, then i should convert into '3.00000000', if my input is 53.678, then i should convert into '53.67800000'. I have googled and tried with few conversion types like parsing, toPrecision() but could not convert it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
expect(a).to.equal(b) // a and be should be of same number with types too
expect(a).to.equal(b)
```

Comment: Numbers to not have trailing zeros. You can used toFixed() which turns it into a string....

Comment: @epascarello, I was expecting the same thing and am able to continue. Thanks much for your fast response. As you answered in the comment, how can i accept your comment as accepted answer?

Comment: Numbers with specific numbers of decimal points are generally only important for output. You shouldn't be using them in internal calculations.

Comment: what do you mean "internal calculations" here? because i have to deal with all my arithmetic calculations with 8 decimal places, as my application is crypto currency based. All dealing with ordering/trading with crypto currencies like bitcoin, etherum etc. also deals with buy amount fees etc. I would like to take any suggestions if you have.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `Number` ***is*** a double-precision float.
Its precision cannot be expressed in *decimal places*, it varies depending on how big the number is. Above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, for example, the precision is "less than 0 decimal places":

```js
const large = 9007199254740992;
const larger = large + 1;
console.log(large === larger);
```

To convert a `Number` to a `String` with a fixed number of decimal places, use `.toFixed()`, as @epascarello suggested:

```js
const input = 3;
const str = input.toFixed(8);
console.log(str);
```

As for doing financial calculations, some say you should never use IEEE 754 floats (such as JavaScript's `Number`s), although many of the largest companies in finance do just that.
To be on the safe side, use a *bignum* library such as [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js).